# HTML/CSS Editor with Multi-Computer Code Folding

Tags: html, css, editor, folding

I'm looking for a code editor that saves folded/collapsed code. I want to be able to open the file on a 2nd computer and have the same folded/collapsed code structure. I understand that HTML/CSS cannot have this preference built in. If the editor needs to save the file in some propriety file type, I'm fine with that. I just need to be able to export it as plain HTML/CSS files once it's ready for publishing.
(Windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

[UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultraedit.html) supports code folding for text files of any type and it supports also saving/restoring of folds on close/open.

In menu **Advanced** there is the menu item **Configuration**. In the settings tree navigate to **Editor Display - Code Folding** and enable at least the settings *Save folded lines* and *Enable show/hide lines and code folding*.

By default UltraEdit remembers which file are open with which lines hidden/folded on exit in file **uedit32.ini** stored on Windows computers by default in directory `%APPDATA%\IDMComp\UltraEdit\`. But this file contains also all other user configurations like the 2 settings I wrote above.

Therefore it is better to use a **project** or at least a **workspace** for editing the HTML/CSS files for your website(s). A project/workspace can be created in menu **Project** with **New Project/Workspace**. Using a project/workspace results in remembering which files are open on closing the project in a separate project related workspace file instead of **uedit32.ini**. The workspace file remembers not only the open files on closing the project, it remebers also which lines are folded, where the caret is positioned in each file, which file was the active file on close, and some other information to restore the workspace on next opening of the project/workspace.

But before creating the project/workspace, you need to enable the setting *Save project information for use on multiple systems* at **Advanced - Configuration - File Handling - Advanced**. As you can read on help page opened by clicking on button **Help** of this configuration dialog, this setting results in storing the workspace file of a project in same directory as the project file.

The location of the project file is defined by you on creating the project/workspace and is quite often in root directory or a subdirectory of a local copy of a website. With *.prj (the project file) and *.pui (the project user interface file = workspace file) somewhere in directory tree of the website, you have those 2 files also shared between multiple systems together with the HTML and CSS files.

See the user forum topics [Create project from an existing directory tree?](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=2265) and [Why save files to a Project?](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=3693) in the user-to-user forums of UltraEdit and take also a look on [Tutorials/Power Tips](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips.html) page of IDM Computer Solutions, Inc.

Comment: I appreciate your help on this and UltraEdit does look like it'll do what I'm wanting. However, is the saving of folded lines in a project file unique to this program? In our company, we just make single, static HTML pages for each 'job' and there was never a need to create a project folder. I'm wondering if creating project files in other programs will save preferences like folded lines as well.

Comment: There is no real need for a project folder if you need this feature just for single HTML pages. You can create a single project/workspace in a directory you want (shared network folder) and add any file you want to the project, or even do not add any file as project file, but use the project as workspace only. Workspace only means there is no project directory configured, there are no files added as project files, there is no Ctags support enabled, ..., just the currently opened files on workspace close respectively exit of UE are remembered and restored on next workspace open/start of UE.

Comment: Of course you can also create one workspace per HTML file which means a *.prj file containing nearly nothing and a *.pui file containing the information to restore the display of the file as on last close of the editing session on this file. Switching from one workspace to another which means from one HTML file to another can be easily done via the **Project** menu or by double clicking on the *.prj file. I'm not using any other text editor. So I don't know what other text editors support.

Answer (score 0):

SynWrite (Windows) supports it. Make some folding, then save a session file (*.syn). This file contains folded states and more. Anytime later, just open session file (menu `File - Sessions`) and folding (and more) restored.

Answer (score 0):

You have a CSSMENU editor where you can create menu bars. This editor saves a file in such a way that it can be moved to any other pc as you mentioned . Html file will be saved and the related Css files are stored in another folder where you can move those files as your wish. No need of changing any code.